# Using framer motion onDrag callback how do I get clientWidth, scrollLeft and scrollWidth for a progress bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js, framer-motion

I'm working on a carousel using framer motion drag gesture which works perfectly, but I'm having an issue implementing logic to the carousel progress bar. I checked the onDrag callback and I couldn't find scrollLeft, scrollWidth, and clientWidth which should be used to calculate and pass to the carousel progress bar.

[carousel with progress-bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPIvO.jpg)

I tried adding ref to the parent Element and I still couldn't find scrollLeft, scrollWidth and clientWidth

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { aboutItems } from "util/about";
import { Box, Flex, Text, Image } from "theme-ui";
import {
    MainContainer,
    NameStyles,
    AboutMeStyles,
    LanguageStyles,
} from "@styles/pages/AboutStyles";
import data from "@public/images.json";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import { motion, useViewportScroll } from "framer-motion";
import { ProgressBar } from "@components";

interface IAboutItems {
    name: string;
    language: string;
}

const About: React.FC = () => {
    const carouselRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();

    const { scrollX } = useViewportScroll();


    const [widthConstraints, setWidthConstraints] = useState<number>(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setWidthConstraints(
            carouselRef.current.scrollWidth - carouselRef.current.offsetWidth,
        );

      
    }, [widthConstraints]);

   
    return (
        <Box sx={MainContainer}>
            <Box
                sx={{
                    mt: ["60px", "80px"],
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    position: "relative",
                }}
              
            >
                <motion.div ref={ref} className="carousel-container">
                    <motion.div
                        className="inner-carousel"
                        ref={carouselRef}
                        drag="x"
                        whileTap={{ cursor: "grabbing" }}
                        dragElastic={0.5}
                        dragConstraints={{ right: 0, left:-widthConstraints }}
                        dragListener={true}
                        onDrag={(event, info) => {
                            console.log("event", { event, info });
                            
                        }}
                    >
                        {data?.carouselItems.map((n, i) => {
                            return (
                                <motion.div className="carousel-items" key={i}>
                                    <motion.div
                                        className="carousel-img"
                                        style={{
                                        backgroundImage:`url(${n.url})`,
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </motion.div>
                            );
                        })}
                    </motion.div>
                </motion.div>
                <Flex
                    className="w-full justify-end"
                    sx={{
                        ml: "auto",
                        fontWeight: 400,
                        lineHeight: "11px",
                        fontFamily: "DotGothic16",
                        fontSize: "9px",
                        fontStyle: "normal",
                        mt: "16px",
                        color: "text",
                    }}
                >
                    horizontal scroll
                </Flex>
                <ProgressBar />
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default About;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.